# Where are the predictions located?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js

When I run `.predict` on my model, I get back a Tensor object but I am having a hard time finding all of my probabilities in one place.

Something I thought would be in the `prediction.array()` but that only yielded one prediction. Curious if the model is not outputting the results or if I am missing a method.

From the tutorials that I've gone through, they simply do;

```
const predictionResult =  this._model.predict(inputTensor).dataSync();
const recognizedDigit = predictionResult.indexOf(Math.max(...predictionResult));
```

The weirdest part to me is that when I do `let result = prediction.dataSync()`, I get back an array with only 1 probability in it, rather than the 5 I expect.

My question is: What method must I do to get all the probabilities for my model's prediction? (Just need confirmation that the model is giving back improper information or if I've missed something)

Comment: It is difficult to answer your question without seeing your model definition and what the prediction output looks like

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one prediction it seems that you have only one neuron in your output layer. so check your model and make sure that your output layer has correct shape.